# Java enterprise architecture for delegating tasks between applications

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, scheduling, message-queue

In my environment I need to schedule long-running task. I have application A which just shows to the client the list of currently running tasks and allows to schedule new ones. There is also application B which does the actual hard work.

So app A needs to schedule a task in app B. The only thing they have in common is the database. The simplest thing to do seems to be adding a table with a list of tasks and having app B query that table every once in a while and execute newly scheduled tasks.

Yet, it doesn't seem to be the proper way of doing it. At first glance it seems that the tool for the job in an enterprise environment is a message queue. App A sends a message with task description to the queue, app B reads a message from the queue and executes the task. Is it possible in such case for app A to get the status of all the tasks scheduled (persistent queue?) without creating a table like the one mentioned above to which app B would write the status of completed tasks? Note also that there may be multiple instances of app A and each of them needs to know about all tasks of all instances.

The disadvantage of the 'table approach' is that I need to have DB polling.

The disadvantage of the 'message queue approach' is that I'm introducing a new communication channel into the infrastructure (yet another thing that can fail).

What do you think? Any other ideas?
Thank you in advance for any advice :)

**========== UPDATE ==========**

Eventually I decided on the following approach: there are two sides of this problem: one is communication between A and B. The other is getting information about the tasks.

For communication the right tool for the job is JMS. For getting data the right tool is the database. 
So I'll have app A add a new row to the 'tasks' table descibing a task (I can query this table later on to get list of all tasks). Then A will send a message to B via JMS just to say 'you have work to do'. B will do the work and update task status in the table.

Thank you for all responses!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to think about your deployment environment both now and likely changes in the future.

You're effectively looking at two problems, both which can be solved in several ways, depending on how much infrastructure you able to obtain and are also willing to introduce, but it's also important to "right size" your design for your problems.

Whilst you're correct to think about the use of both databases and messaging, you need to consider whether these items are overkill for your domain and only you and others who know your domain can really answer that.

My advice would be to look at what is already in use in your area. If you already have database infrastructure that you can build into, then monitoring task activity and scheduling jobs in a database are not a bad idea. However, if you would have to run your own database, get new hardware, don't have sufficient support resources then introduction of a database may not be a sensible option and you could look at a simpler, but potentially more fragile approach of having your processes write files to schedule jobs and report tasks.

At the same time, don't look at the introduction of a DB or JMS as inherently error prone. Correctly implemented they are stable and proven technologies that will make your system scalable and manageable.

As @kan says, use exposing an web service interface is also a useful option.

Comment: Thanks, I'm marking this as the answer, because it has been most useful to me and helped me find the solution. I will describe what I chose in an update of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have [messages (JMS)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/overview.html#1027335) in enterprise architecture. Use these, they are available in Java EE containers like Glassfish. Messages can be serialized to be sure they will be delivered even if the server reboots while they are in the queue. And you even do not need to care how all this is implemented.

Comment: Thank you, I will use JMS :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make the B as a service, e.g. expose control and status interfaces as REST or SOAP interfaces. In this case the A will just be as a client application of the B. The B stores its state in the database. The A is a stateless application which just communicates with B.

BTW, using Spring Remote you could expose an interface and use any of JMS, REST, SOAP or RMI as a transport layer which could be changed later if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in my case this is not really an option, because then I loose the benefit of having multiple instances of app A (because even when I want to just get the status of tasks, application B - which is just one - has to do it too). I will have a look at Spring Remote though :)

Comment: @machinery Vice versa: because the A is just a client, the B is a server. In this case the B could easily handle as much A clients as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There can be couple of approaches here. First, as @kan suggested to have app B expose some web service for the interactions. This will heterogenous clients to communicate with app B. Seems a good approach. App B can internally use whatever persistent store it deems fit.

Alternatively, you can have app B expose some management interface via JMX and have applications like app A talk to app B through this management interface. Implementing the task submission and retrieving the statistics etc. would be simpler. Additionally, you can also leverage JMX notifications for real time updates on task submissions and accomplishments etc. Downside to this is that this would be a Java specific solution and hence supporting heterogenous clients will be distant dream.

Comment: thanks, eventually I decided for something else, but your note about JMX features has been rather interesting to me. Will remember this for the future :)